# Error when trying to display resources in fullCalendar

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

I have a problem to return an array in FullCalendar 1.5.4, with the resource day view (Source : https://github.com/ikelin/fullcalendar ).

**Here my controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetResources()
    {        
    var data =db.Patients.ToList();            
    return Json(data.Select(i => new
        {
            id = i.PatientID,
            name = i.FirstName + " " + i.LastName
        }),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Here my view:**

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'resourceDay',
        resources: function (callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetResources", "Patient")',
                success: function (d) {                        
                    var listOfResources = [];
                        for (var i = 0, len = d.length; i < len; i++) {
                            var item = d[i];
                            listOfResources.push(item);
                            console.log(listOfResources[i].name);
                        }
                        callback(listOfResources);
                },

                    error: function (e) {
                        debugger;
                    }
            });
       }
 })
```

**Here my json result**

```
0       Object { id=1, name="Marie Curie"}  
1       Object { id=2, name="Gustave Eiffel"}
```

**and my response :**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Marie Curie"},{"id":2,"name":"Gustave Eiffel"}]
```

**the return of console.log(listOfResources[i].name) :**

```
Marie Curie
Gustave Eiffel
```

**Here my error:**

```
TypeError: resources[i] is undefined
headCell.html(resources[i].name);
```

Comment: Could you include the function that is serving as your callback? Looks like the problem is not with the code you posted.

Comment: function callback(array){return array}

Comment: and now function callback undefined

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you have not defined `ListOfResources`, so `callback(ListOfResources);` would not work.

I believe you want to pass in `listOfResources into the`callback`. Notice the different casing:

```
callback(listOfResources)
```

Comment: The error of cast was done when I had copied the code into Stackoverflow :) So the error doesn't come from there